# when making a binding lib for xamarin android you need to adapt the functions with out parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin, jar, android-databinding

I have a .jar library that I have added as EmbebedJar. Among them there is a function that returns an integer and asks for two parameters, a context and a list in which the readers are going to be listed. When I use that function, it returns ok, but it doesn't fill the list with readers.

```
public virtual long SCardListReaders(Android.Content.Context p0, System.Collections.IList p1)
```

I can not debug the code because I have the USB port busy, but I add a log output file.

```
private bool ReloadReader()
{
    bool ret = false;
    try
    {
        _SmartCard = new SCard();

        long succes = _SmartCard.SCardEstablishContext(Application.Context);
        if (succes == 0)
        {
            succes = _SmartCard.USBRequestPermission(Application.Context);
            if (succes == 0)
            {
                System.Collections.IList tempReadersList = new List<string>();
                succes = _SmartCard.SCardListReaders(Application.Context, tempReadersList);
                List<string> readersList = (List<string>)tempReadersList;

                if (succes == 0 && readersList != null && readersList.Count() > 0)
                {
                    ret = true;
                }
            }
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ret = false;
        new LogRepository(DbPath).SaveLog(_context, LogType.Error, "Error in ReloadReader", ex);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

ListReaders returns ok, but no readers in the list.

Comment: According to your description, the `ret`'s value is true and the `readersList`'s value is null? Can you check the value of `readersList.Count()`?

Comment: readersList.Count() = 0

Comment: If so, the ListReaders shouldn't return ok. So there is something wrong in the SCardListReaders method.